# Read content of file in Java without updating last access time

Tags: java, lastaccesstime

I am looking for a way to read the content of a file in Java without updating the last access time of the file.  In C on Linux this is achieved by passing the [`O_NOATIME` flag to `open`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), and I'm sure other languages and platforms have similar mechanisms.

I'm using [`Files.newInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#newInputStream(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) which has various options that can be passed, but none that appear to match `O_NOATIME`.

Is there a way to read the content of a file in Java on a unix-like platform without updating the last access time of the file?

Comment: i'm not sure. but cant you copy the file and read it. once done you remove it the copie ?

Comment: Copying a file requires accessing (reading) it @Hamza.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to do this in Java (apart from implementing it natively with JNI OFC). I grepped [JDK sources at Github](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk) for instances of `O_NOATIME` and didn't get any hits.

If you peek into the [UnixChannelFactory class](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/07669e3bc65b1728d784e21ec83b437374f9fa19/src/java.base/unix/classes/sun/nio/fs/UnixChannelFactory.java) you can see the [Flags class](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/07669e3bc65b1728d784e21ec83b437374f9fa19/src/java.base/unix/classes/sun/nio/fs/UnixChannelFactory.java#L56) which, I think, lists all supported options:

```
protected static class Flags {
    boolean read;
    boolean write;
    boolean append;
    boolean truncateExisting;
    boolean noFollowLinks;
    boolean create;
    boolean createNew;
    boolean deleteOnClose;
    boolean sync;
    boolean dsync;
    boolean direct;

    static Flags toFlags(Set<? extends OpenOption> options) {
        Flags flags = new Flags();
        for (OpenOption option: options) {
            if (option instanceof StandardOpenOption) {
                switch ((StandardOpenOption)option) {
                    case READ : flags.read = true; break;
                    case WRITE : flags.write = true; break;
                    case APPEND : flags.append = true; break;
                    case TRUNCATE_EXISTING : flags.truncateExisting = true; break;
                    case CREATE : flags.create = true; break;
                    case CREATE_NEW : flags.createNew = true; break;
                    case DELETE_ON_CLOSE : flags.deleteOnClose = true; break;
                    case SPARSE : /* ignore */ break;
                    case SYNC : flags.sync = true; break;
                    case DSYNC : flags.dsync = true; break;
                    default: throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }
                continue;
            }
            if (option == LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS && O_NOFOLLOW != 0) {
                flags.noFollowLinks = true;
                continue;
            }

            if (ExtendedOptions.DIRECT.matches(option)) {
                flags.direct = true;
                continue;
            }

            if (option == null)
                throw new NullPointerException();
           throw new UnsupportedOperationException(option + " not supported");
        }
        return flags;
    }
}
```

As a workaround you can revert the last access time after accessing the file:

```
// Create a file and write some content (empty files don't have their last access time updated after accessing - at least on Windows)
Path file = Files.createTempFile(null, null);
Files.write(file, Arrays.asList("line 1", "line 2"));

// Retrieve the last access time attribute before accessing the file    
FileTime lastAccessTimeBeforeAccessing = getLastAccessTime(file);

// Access the file
Files.readAllLines(file);

// Retrieve the last access time attribute after accessing the file 
FileTime lastAccessTimeAfterAccessing = getLastAccessTime(file);

// Revert the last access time
Files.setAttribute(file, "basic:lastAccessTime", lastAccessTimeBeforeAccessing);

// Retrieve the last access time attribute after reverting it   
FileTime lastAccessTimeAfterReverting = getLastAccessTime(file);

// at this point:
// * lastAccessTimeBeforeAccessing.equals(lastAccessTimeAfterAccessing) is false
// * lastAccessTimeBeforeAccessing.equals(lastAccessTimeAfterReverting) is true
```

The `getLastAccessTime` function is:

```
private static FileTime getLastAccessTime(Path file) throws IOException {
    BasicFileAttributes basicFileAttributes = Files.readAttributes(
        file, BasicFileAttributes.class);
    return basicFileAttributes.lastAccessTime();
}
```

Comment: Adding a blank line after `Files.write` and after `Files.setAttribute` will make your example more readable, by isolating the code that actually addresses the question from the code which is just setup/demonstration.  Also, to make it easier for readers to incorporate, you can simply call `Files.createTempFile(null, null)`, so readers don’t have to guess what `temp` is.  And I recommend writing out `Arrays.asList` for clarity.

Comment: I cleaned it up a bit @VGR.